# Why is a SCSI disk not showing up?

Tags: hardware, disk, iscsi

I have a Seagate SCSI disk that is installed in my ***Kurwel 2500R*** sampler which I send files to via the computer. I had this system running on my Windows machine, but am not able to get it configured properly for Ubuntu 12.04

The SCSI disk is showing up in the BIOS, and in the Kurzweil, but I can't seem to get Ubuntu to see it. I have used GParted with no results. The SCSI drive is connected via a PCI slot in the computer.

`lspci` output for SCSI is:

```
04:00.0 SCSI storage controller: Tekram Technology Co.,Ltd. TRM-S1040 (rev 01)
```

More information:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda 8:0 0 74.5G 0 disk 
 ├─sda1 8:1 0 72.5G 0 part / 
 ├─sda2 8:2 0 1K 0 part 
 └─sda5 8:5 0 2G 0 part (in gparted this partition is unreadable)
 └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) 252:0 0 2G 0 crypt sdb 8:16 0 931.5G 0 disk 
 └─sdb1 8:17 0 931.5G 0 part /media/trunk sr0 11:0 1 621.1M 0 rom
```

(none of these drives seem to be the 4 gig SCSI drive which is a SEAGATE)

lsscsi outputs this:

> [0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD800JD-75MS 10.0  /dev/sda
>   [1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50  TN00  /dev/sr0
>   [2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDT72101 ST6O  /dev/sdb
>   [4:0:6:0]    process Kurzweil K2500            3.02  -

(the bottom is my Kurzweil where the drive is installed, but this is SCSI 7 and I need to access the DRIVE inside the Kurzweil which is SCSI 2)

I have recently discovered that the PCI card I use **04:00.0 SCSI storage controller: Tekram Technology Co.,Ltd. TRM-S1040 (rev 01)** would need a driver.

After googling, I found this article:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1535201

I installed the package `kernel-patch-tekram-dc3x5_1.41-2_all.deb`, hoping that this would get UBUNTU to recognize my drive. After reboot still the drive is absent. Below is a description of the driver. I need to know if this is the right one for the kernel I have?

***"DC3x5 is a SCSI host by Tekram which is not supported out of the box by
the Linux kernel. This patch adds support for the card to the Linux kernel.
The cards supported are DC315 and DC395, both based on the TRM-S1040
chipset.
This package supports 2.2.20 & 2.4.18 kernels. Older and newer 2.2.x and
2.4.x should work too. It should also work and will attempt to apply to 2.5 and
2.0 kernel versions"***

Looks like I have 3.11.0-18-generic kernel so this won't work.

Ideas?

Comment: I'd wager you're missing a necessary kernel module. Can you post the output of your "lspci -v"?

Comment: What does `lsblk` show?

Comment: Looks like it's there just fine... you have /dev/sdb1 mounted in /media/trunk...

Comment: @psusi that is not the SCSI drive though. that is my other media drive. The SCSI drive is a 4 gig drive.

Comment: Have to take a look at /var/log/syslog then...

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: ok here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7445247/

Comment: Looks like the controller is working ( despite appearing to be very ancient ) but the drive is buggy: scsi 4:0:2:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery

Comment: thanks @psusi but i am confused. What does it mean offlined? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: It means it is disabled, shut down, not used, kaput...  doesn't look like there's anything you can do.

Comment: Seth suggested maybe doing a dual boot machine with the older Kernel that that driver is for. I guess that's the only option then.

Comment: Does it still work if you attach it to your Windows machine again? If not, the drive has likely failed. 4GB SCSI is very very old and should be replaced if it hasn't failed already

Comment: @ElderGeek the drive is working fine (shows up in the sampler OS as readable and I can navigate the files). The only reason a drive this old is being used is because the K2500R sampler wont take drives any larger.

Comment: Readable? Is it writeable?

Comment: @ElderGeek yes to both.

Comment: Please follow up and let us know how this is progressing so that others can benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: I am now trying to figure out how to install a second Ubuntu OS to try out this kernel-patch-tekram-dc3x5_1.41. I downloaded 2.4.18 kernel but do not know what to do now.

Comment: @ElderGeek do you think he maybe has to change the IRQ and DMA? (Not even sure you can do that in BIOS anymore or not)

Comment: @NoTime I would think that if he patches an appropriate kernel it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the driver should be available in newer kernels (under the name dc395x), but might not be activated/compiled by default. Does a `sudo modprobe dc395x` help? According to [this](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SCSI_DC395x.html), it is the right module for your card.

Comment: hi thank you for your response. I am relatively new to ubuntu, so not sure exactly what steps to take. I typed in *sudo modprobe dc395x* in terminal but nothing happened. I do not know how to install a module, or even what a module is. ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: No error message after modprobe is a good sign already. After the modprobe, do the `lssci` again, do you see your drive now? Also, is `dmesg | tail` mentioning scsi devices? A kernel module is more or less a driver in this case. You can load it manually with `modprobe`, to load it automatically you add `dc395x` to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: `lsscsi` outputs the same as above ** [4:0:6:0] process Kurzweil K2500 3.02 - ** but no drive. The output of `dmesg | tail`  [link](washttp://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7920713/) -

Comment: Also, i should state that the kernel I have now is 3.11.0 - 18

Comment: 3.11 should also be fine. The `dmesg` output you posted only contained firewall messages, you can remove the link. Can you just add `dc395x` to `/etc/modules` and reboot to see if that changes anything in the lssci output, or if you get a `/dev/scsi0` device or similar?

Comment: I have no `/etc/modules` dir. what should i do?

Comment: `/etc/modules` is a file. Add a line at the end that reads `dc395x`. To do so, use an editor like nano: `sudo nano /etc/modules`. Add the line at the end, and save with ctrl-o and leave with ctrl-x

Comment: hi @noleti  ok I added that but it didnt do anything, but I did notice something when I put in `sudo sg_scan -i` the output was /dev/sg3: scsi4 channel=0 id=6 lun=0 . The scsi ID number 6 is allocated to the K2500r but I need to access ID number 2 (which is the drive inside the k2500r). Also now when I type in `sudo sg_scan -i`the k2500 freezes up. This did not happen before I put `dc395x` into the modules file and rebooted

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: Can't help you much more than that. the `dc395x` should be the correct kernel module for your card, and you have it available on your machine. I don't know how to configure it, and last time I used scsi was 10 years ago.

Comment: Well, it seems the card is working. It's being read, only problem is that UBUNTU is seeing SCSI 6 and not the other drives connected on SCSI 2. Still not sure what to do here, but Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options you can try.

1) Try obtaining a version of the kernel that you can patch. (Set up dual boot at you say Seth suggested in the comments) You can find versions of the kernel in the range your patch specifies [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/)

2) [Migrate](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows) your Windows installation to Virtual box

How to do either of these approaches is fully documented elsewhere and either approach triggers a different question which has likely been asked and answered long ago. I hesitate to create more duplication.

Comment: Link provided at Migrate above.

Comment: I installed WIndows Virtual BOx (a fresh install of windows, not a migrated one) and this did not work, as the drive is not recognized in Ubuntu, so there is no way too add it. I saw the controller card come up in the device manager for the Virtual Machine, but it had error code 10, and would not let me access the card.

Comment: Did you obtain a patchable kernel as in step 1 of my answer above?

Comment: yes I have obtained 2.4.18 kernel for the DC3x5 kernel patch, but do not know how to proceed with that.I keep hearing about modules, compiling, backing up stuff, but i have no clue what all that means. As mentioned above by *noleti*, it seems there is a module that works for the kernels up till 3.8 (i am running 3.11.0-18-generic now). *http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SCSI_DC395x.html* where do i go from here?

Comment: You could try this: http://cateee.net/autokernconf/